# Symbian sis file installation failed

Tags: qt, symbian, sis

Im developing a QT application which includes QTMobility and QContacts, QMessaging and QSystemInfo.

Following [this documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/quickstart.html).

my .pro file has following capabilities

```
symbian::TARGET.CAPABILITY = LocalServices ReadUserData WriteUserData NetworkServices UserEnvironment ReadDeviceData WriteDeviceData Location
```

However while installing the sis file, I get the error "Requested application access not granted"

Am I missing some capabilities or are there too many of them

Answer (score 3):

You have to sign you sis file with a valid certificate in order to install it.
I assume that you use QT Creator IDE. It self-signs sis files by default. Self-signing can be used for the set of basic capabilities which include only:

```
ReadUserData WriteUserData NetworkServices LocalServices UserEnvironment
```

If you really need your application to use `ReadDeviceData WriteDeviceData Location` you must sign your sis file with a developer certificate. This is how you can get your certificate. You have several options here:

1. If you have a Publisher ID you can get a certificate at [symbiansigned.com](http://symbiansigned.com). To get a Publisher ID for 1 year will cost you $200 and to apply you must represent a registered organization. Individual developers can not apply for a Publisher ID.
2. Sign your sis file with [Open Signed Online](https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do). It's free and anyone can use it. But you will have to go there and sign your sis each time you rebuild your application.
3. For a mere €1 you can become an [Ovi Publisher](http://info.publish.ovi.com/). Registration is available for both companies and individual developers. After you register Ovi will provide you a developer certificate for up to 5 IMEI numbers of your test devices.

Hope this was helpful. Good luck!

Comment: As for 1st January 2014 all official options for signing Symbian apps or getting DevCert are gone. Please if anyone knows about something which works let me know.